# Error while Switching Data from Master to Archive - Partition Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables as follows where in the later is a table for storing the archived data.

```js
CREATE TABLE [ERP].[Transaction](
 [TransactionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
 [TransactionDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [TransactionName] [int] NOT NULL,
 [TransactionData] [xml] NOT NULL,
 [AcknowledgementDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
 [AcknowledgementCode] [int] NULL,
 [AcknowledgementDescription] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [TransactionGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 [WorkCenter] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pkTransaction] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
 [TransactionID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
)

GO

ALTER TABLE [ERP].[Transaction] ADD  CONSTRAINT [defTransactionTransactionGUID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [TransactionGUID]
GO
```

```js
CREATE TABLE [ERP].[TransactionArchived](
 [TransactionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [TransactionDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [TransactionName] [int] NOT NULL,
 [TransactionData] [xml] NOT NULL,
 [AcknowledgementDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
 [AcknowledgementCode] [int] NULL,
 [AcknowledgementDescription] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [TransactionGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 [WorkCenter] [nvarchar](10) NULL
)

GO
```

I have made partition as follows and create Indexes to support the partition.

```js
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PartitionXFaceDataByMonthPF ( DATETIME )
       AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ( '2010-01-01', '2010-02-01', '2010-03-01', '2010-04-01', '2010-05-01', '2010-06-01', '2010-07-01', '2010-08-01', '2010-09-01', '2010-10-01', '2010-11-01', '2010-12-01',
                                     '2011-01-01', '2011-02-01', '2011-03-01', '2011-04-01', '2011-05-01', '2011-06-01', '2011-07-01', '2011-08-01', '2011-09-01', '2011-10-01', '2011-11-01', '2011-12-01',
                                                   '2012-01-01', '2012-02-01', '2012-03-01', '2012-04-01', '2012-05-01', '2012-06-01', '2012-07-01', '2012-08-01', '2012-09-01', '2012-10-01', '2012-11-01', '2012-12-01',
                                                   '2013-01-01', '2013-02-01', '2013-03-01', '2013-04-01', '2013-05-01', '2013-06-01', '2013-07-01', '2013-08-01', '2013-09-01', '2013-10-01', '2013-11-01', '2013-12-01',
                                                   '2014-01-01', '2014-02-01', '2014-03-01', '2014-04-01', '2014-05-01', '2014-06-01', '2014-07-01', '2014-08-01', '2014-09-01', '2014-10-01', '2014-11-01', '2014-12-01',
                                                   '2015-01-01', '2015-02-01', '2015-03-01', '2015-04-01', '2015-05-01', '2015-06-01', '2015-07-01', '2015-08-01', '2015-09-01', '2015-10-01', '2015-11-01', '2015-12-01' ) ;


--Create the PARTITION SCHEME
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PartitionXFaceDataByMonthPS AS PARTITION PartitionXFaceDataByMonthPF ALL TO ( [PRIMARY] ) ;
```

```js
Index Creation 
ALTER TABLE [ERP].[Transaction] DROP CONSTRAINT [pkTransaction] ;
ALTER TABLE [ERP].[Transaction] ADD CONSTRAINT [pkTransaction] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ( [TransactionID] ASC ) ON [PRIMARY] ;
/****** Object:  Index [idxTransactionDateTime]    Script Date: 01/14/2016 15:53:28 ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[ERP].[Transaction]') AND name = N'idxTransactionDateTime')
DROP INDEX [idxTransactionDateTime] ON [ERP].[Transaction] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idxTransactionDateTime ON [ERP].[Transaction]( [TransactionDateTime] ) ON PartitionXFaceDataByMonthPS( [TransactionDateTime] ) ;
--DROP TABLE [ERP].[TransactionArchived] ; --This needs to execute only if we rerun the same set onace again on the same DB
SELECT * INTO [ERP].[TransactionArchived] FROM [ERP].[Transaction] WHERE 1 = 2 ;
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idxTransactionDateTime ON [ERP].[TransactionArchived] ( TransactionDateTime ) ON PartitionXFaceDataByMonthPS( [TransactionDateTime] ) ;
--CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [pkTransaction] ON [ERP].[TransactionArchived] ( [TransactionID] ) ON PartitionXFaceDataByMonthPS( [TransactionDateTime] ) ;
GO
```

When I am switching data it gives an error as follows which I am struggling to find a solution. Please help

**'ALTER TABLE SWITCH' statement failed. The table 'EPMSDataExchange.ERP.Transaction' is partitioned while index 'pkTransaction' is not partitioned.**

thanks
pep

Comment: Please read the Stack Overflow FAQ on the correct way to ask a question.

Comment: I see you also asked this question on the Microsoft MSDN forums and have an answer there: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ff73338c-6bcf-4f79-8850-adf605016cd8/error-whle-switching-from-archive-partition-table-to-master-table?forum=transactsql